Looking for definition of function spaces appearing in article of DiPerna & Lions
I am looking for the definition of various function spaces appearing in the following article, preferably with references to other sources where such spaces are discussed in greater detail:
Article: DiPerna & Lions (1989): Ordinary differential equations, transport theory and Sobolev Spaces. Invent. Math., 98, 511–547.
In §II.1 (page 514), the authors initiate the study of the scalar transport equation
$$\partial_t u - b \cdot \nabla_x u + cu = 0 \quad \text{in } (0,T) \times \mathbb{R}^N,$$
where they 'always assume that $b, c$ satisfy at least
$$b \in L^1\bigl(0,T; (L^1_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^N)^N\bigr), \quad c \in L^1\bigl( 0, T; L^1_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^N) \bigr)\text{'.}$$
This is equation (12). Similar spaces appear in equation (14): '… assume
$$c + \mathop{div} b \in L^1\bigl( 0,T; L^q_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^N) \bigr), \quad b \in L^1\bigl( 0,T; ( L^q_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^N) )^N \bigr)\text{',}$$
or equation (18), page 516:
$$b \in L^1\bigl( 0, T; W^{1,\alpha}_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^N) \bigr),$$
or indeed throughout the rest of the paper.
Question: What exactly are the spaces $L^1\bigl( 0,T; E \bigr)$ with $E = L^p_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ or $E = W^{1,\alpha}_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^N)$?
These are probably standard spaces for seasoned practitioners, considering the authors' lack of pointing to their definitions.
I am familiar with the Bochner integral and the corresponding spaces $L^1(0, T; E)$ when $E$ is a Banach space. But $L^p_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and the local Sobolev spaces $W^{1,\alpha}_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ are to my knowledge not Banach spaces in any standard way. Hence the Bochner integral is not directly applicable.
I understand that these spaces must consist of families $(c_t)_{ t \in [0,T] }$, etc., of functions in $L^p_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, but I am unsure about the meaning of the time-integrability of $t \mapsto c_t$ as a map $[0,T] \to L^p_\text{loc}$.

Suggestion: $u \in L^1(0, T; L^1_\text{loc})$ iff $u \colon [0,T] \to L^1_\text{loc}$ is such that $(t \mapsto u(t)\vert_K) \in L^1(0, T; L^1(K))$ for each compact $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$.

Sobolev spaces with values in an arbitrary metric space can be defined, for example by embedding the metric space isometrically in a Banach space via the Kuratowski embedding. See the book 'Sobolev Spaces on Metric Measure Spaces' by Heinonen et al. page 189.

Thanks. I will have a look at it and return here later.
